# How to remove largefiles from mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, repository, large-files

I enabled the largefiles extension, committed a file and pushed it. I need to permanently revert this change. How can I do it? Is there a way to make this permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're added the file like this

```
$ hg add --large my-file
```

then Mercurial will have committed a file called `.hglf/my-file` to the repository (the so-called standin file) and it will have pushed `my-file` to the remote server when you pushed your commit.

If you disable the largefiles extension, then all there is left in your history is the `.hglf/my-file` file. You can delete this file like normal with

```
$ hg remove .hglf/my-file
```

The standin file will still be present in the history, just like any other file Mercurial has been tracking. But the large file (`my-file`) is not part of the normal Mercurial history and so you wont see it in new clones where you haven't enabled the largefiles extension.